# html_text captures unwanted css data

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape some information from a website. The problem is, when I use `html_text`, it captures information that I don't need:

```
"https://tomsk.drom.ru/toyota/bb/49660653.html" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements("tr:nth-child(2) .ezjvm5n0") %>%
  html_text()
```

The output is:

```
[1] ".css-9g0qum{line-height:1.55;}109 л.с., .css-1dauskf{-webkit-text-decoration:none;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;color:var(--link, hsl(209, 77%, 45%));border:none;background:none;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;padding:0;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px dashed var(--light-blue-button-bg, hsl(208, 100%, 92%));}.drom-notouch .css-1dauskf:hover,.drom-touch .css-1dauskf:active{-webkit-text-decoration:none;text-decoration:none;color:var(--drom-brand, hsl(353, 100%, 43%));border-bottom:1px dashed var(--link-hover-border, hsla(353, 100%, 43%, 0.2));}налог"
```

instead of just:

```
[1] "109 л.с., налог"
```

There was an idea to use regular expressions but I'm afraid I can't cover all the cases

Answer (score 2):

It comes from a style-element that somehow gets through `html_text()`. And I would have thought that at least `html_text2()` would discard that content, but apparently not. While this can likely be achieved through selectors (`:not()` ?) / XPath too, we can also just remove those `<style>` elements:

```r
library(rvest)

remove_style <- function(elements){
  html_elements(elements, "style") %>% 
    xml2::xml_remove(free = TRUE)
  elements
}

"https://tomsk.drom.ru/toyota/bb/49660653.html" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements("tr:nth-child(2) .ezjvm5n0") %>% 
  remove_style() %>% 
  html_text2()
#> [1] "109 л.с., налог"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>